# return multiple pandas.DataFrames from functions and export as different files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def myfunc(arg1,arg2):
    df1 = pd.Datframe() #uses arg1 and arg2; df1 has 10cols & 100rows
    df2 = pd.Datframe() #uses arg1 and arg2; df2 has 4cols & 10rows
    return df1, df2

result = myfunc(arg1,arg2)
```

I need to extract the individual df from result and export as .xlsx

Comment: Hi,  there is an AttributeError:'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return a tuple, which is iterable. You can export the results like this:

```
import uuid
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

for r in result:
    r.to_excel(writer, str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

This will write your files in .xlsx format, and assign each file a unique name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence unpacking:

```
def myfunc(arg1,arg2):
    df1 = pd.Datframe() #uses arg1 and arg2; df1 has 10cols & 100rows
    df2 = pd.Datframe() #uses arg1 and arg2; df2 has 4cols & 10rows
    return df1, df2

df1, df2 = myfunc(arg1,arg2)

df1.to_excel('data1.xlsx')
df2.to_excel('data2.xlsx')
```

Or you can iterate in a loop:

```
for idx, df in enumerate(myfunc(arg1, arg2)):
    df.to_excel('data{0}.xlsx'.format(idx))
```

Comment: r in result: df1 = pd.DataFrame(r[0]); df2=pd.DataFrame(r[1])...Worked for me...thanks